# How to use STI routes path?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, sti

I have a STI models

```
class Fruit < ActiveRecord::Base; end
class Apple < Fruit; end
class Orange < Fruit; end
```

and routes:

```
resources :fruits
resources :apples, controller: 'fruits', type: 'Apple'
resources :oranges, controller: 'fruits', type: 'Orange'
```

the scaffold create the view which use `new_fruit_path` to create new fruit

when I go to `localhost:3000\apples`, and click new button, it will go to `localhost:3000\fruits\new` page.

Is there any way that going to the `localhost:3000\apples\new` page? I don't want to create a new view that with `new_apple_path`

Thanks.

Comment: why you dont want using `new_apple_path`?

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ because I only want one view for new action, which means a new.html.erb can be used for fruit, apple, orange creation.

Comment: Then you are able to use the only view in many action for all three controllers as render "fruits/new"

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ Yes, that's what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Just do the following:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :fruits #-> url.com/fruits/new

#app/controllers/fruits_controller.rb
class FruitsController < ApplicationController
   def new
      @type = params[:type].constantize if params[:type]
      @fruit = @type.new
   end
end
```

You'll then be able to use:

```
<%= link_to "New Apple", new_fruit_path(type: "apple") %>
```

... it will probably look crappy in the URL though: `url.com/fruits/new?type=apple`

--

Conversely, this would be prudent to look at your STI structure if you're having an issue like this. You might be better using an [`enum`](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html), removing the "subclass" layer which will just add complication for no reason.

---

BTW you might be able to use the [`polymorphic_path`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/PolymorphicRoutes.html) helper if you wanted to use a path helper and have it adapt to whichever object you pass.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't want to create a new view for a new specific product, you can just render the common view for `new` action for the all STI inherited classes, so:

```
class FruitsController < ApplicationController
   def new
      # do something
      render 'fruits/new'
   end
```